# CSRF risk in Ajax

Tags: ajax, symfony, csrf

I'm using [Symfony2](http://www.symfony.com) and protecting my forms with a CSRF token.
I have a comments system based on **Ajax** calls. If a user wants to edit his comment, here's what's happening:

- A user hits the *edit* button.
- A *"fresh"* comment edit form is loaded via ajax.
- The user edit and submit the form via ajax.
- The edited comment is sent back in response.

#### Is loading the *"fresh"* edit form via ajax a security risk?

If the form were already in the loaded page and couldn't be requested via ajax, an attacker could not guess the CSRF Token, but since he can request the form he can get his hands on the Token..
Couldn't he..?

#### Maybe an example will make it clearer:

*Dave* is an innocent registered user in my site (`www.acme.com`).
*Dave* logged in my site and then visited `www.evil.com`. He doesn't know that, but when he visited `evil.com` a script was executed.
The script sent an ajax request to `www.acme.com/comments/123/edit` and got the edit form in response.
It then filled in that form with it's malicious content and submitted that form (again, with ajax).

**Will *evil's* evil plan work?**

Comment: can you add your code so we can understand your question more

Comment: I could but that'll just make a mess. my question is more theoretical.. not for a specific code

Comment: so this way @Ziumin has a good point in his answer

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand, there is no risk if your form contains CSRF token field. Default Symfony2 CSRF token depends on session which is not availiable for the attacker (and also on intention). So when the attacker requests the form there is attacker's (not user's) session id used.

Comment: If a legitimate user enters an external site, and that (evil) site silently request the form from my web (e.g. sending an ajax request to www.mysite.com/comment/2/edit) and then submit that form, that form will be valid, wouldn't it? since it all happens from the legitimate user's pc..

Comment: Cross-domain ajax is not an easy thing even if you have a direct access to both domains. So do not worry about it